# Column sort is not putting numbers in the correct order

Tags: csv, sorting

I am uploading a .csv file into a third-party program with the following data for example:

[image]

When the (third party) program sorts this data by the 'Number' column it looks like it is sorting the column by the first character and not the number as a whole.

For example it would sort this list like:
1, 10, 11, 12....

Instead of:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5....

Is this something to do with the .csv file, or something sorting function in the program?

Is there another column I can add that will sort this type of table correctly?

Comment: Why not share the name of the program?

Comment: Change the format of the column to numeric.

Comment: I am uploading it into a shipping software managed by FedEx. No matter what format the column is when when I import it, it appears that the application defaults to reading it as 'text' instead of a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

##### Text vs. Numbers

The issue exists because your values are being sorted as text strings not as numbers.  In other words, like a dictionary, sorted by first character, then by second, then third, and so on.

Solutions:

1. Instruct your program to see the values as numbers
2. Prepend enough zeros onto each number so that all numbers have matching lengths

<sub>**Text vs. Number Sorts**</sub>
[image]